# How to use knex.js in browser

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I hope you can help me here. 
I tried to use knex.js (http://knexjs.org/#Installation-browser) outside of node for my multiplayer game and I don't understand how to use it on client side. Im really really new to node, webpacker, browserify etc.

Can anyone give me an example? 
I integrate the file like

```html
<script src="lib/knex.js"></script>
```

and wont it to use like this:

```js
var mysql = Knex({client: 'websql',
                     connection: {
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'battleground'
  }
});
```

Console output: Uncaught ReferenceError: Knex is not defined

Sorry for my bad english too!

I Hope for help - Thank you.

Best regards,

Oleg

Answer (score 0):

Remove connection because you can't do connection, only query.

And then you have to use Webpack v4...and do a lot of patch-package work on knex itself to make it compatible for Web, it's no longer compatible out of the box.

Answer (score -2):

Just started playing with knex in the browser. This code will load knex but it won't make a database connection.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="lodash.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bluebird.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="knex.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function(){
        var webSql = Knex({client: 'websql'
        });
        var sql = webSql.select('name').from('client').toString();
        console.log(sql);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you loading `knex.min.js` from?